# Cannot set deployment target below OSX 10.8 (Error: dyld: Library not loaded -- Reason: Incompatible library version)

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, frameworks, build

I am trying to build and run an Cocoa-based OSX app. However, when I attempt to set the deployment target to anything other than 10.8, I get a runtime error when the app attempts to launch:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
  Referenced from: /Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Release/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
  Reason: Incompatible library version: MyApp requires version 64.0.0 or later, but ApplicationServices provides version 1.0.0
```

As far as I can tell, there is nothing in my app that uses anything from the ApplicationServices.framework. I don't even know why it would attempt to load that library.

For reference, I'm using a few 3rd party frameworks, including Growl.framework (Growl 2.0), Sparkle.framework (Sparkle 1.5 b6), and MagicKit.framework (https://github.com/aidansteele/MagicKit)

Comment: Just to be clear - the error ONLY happens if I change the Deployment target to something other than 10.8. If the Deployment target is 10.8, there is no runtime loading error.

Comment: Have the 3rd party frameworks been compiled to work with systems < 10.8?

Comment: All the 3rd party frameworks claim to be able to work with 10.6, which is the OSX version I'm trying to target. However, even when I remove them and their dependent code from my project, I still receive the runtime error.

Comment: Xcode Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a)

Comment: I was unable to reproduce; Xcode 4.5.2 was able to build for a 10.6 deployment target for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question (after several hours of investigation):

Apparently, by linking to CoreGraphics.framework in my Desktop app project, it caused a runtime load request for the 10.8 version of the ApplicationServices framework. Fortunately, I  wasn't even using anything from CoreGraphics. Removing caused the dyld loading error to stop.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to have the ***ApplicationServices.framework*** added
to the ***Link Binary With Libraries*** Phase in your target's Build Phase tab.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error by trying to use symbols in CoreGraphics and importing <CoreGraphics/CGGeometry.h> directly, instead of the recommended <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h> as specified by the documentation.

Believe it or not, even in 10.8, you're still supposed to be importing AND linking ApplicationServices for this.